# .htaccess rewrite without redirect / Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite an URL so that "few_words_Keyword" is shown in the browser but the page display /directory/Keyword

In my htaccess I have following :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule few_words_(.*)$ /directory/$1 [L,R,NC]
```

It works with R and it redirects to the page /directory/Keyword but without R I get an 404 error.

Edit : the URL /directory/$1 is not "real" it is another redirection which is managed by Wordpress :

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you help me ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So what _is_ `/directory/Keyword`? Is that a physically existing file or directory? Or do you have more rewriting in place, to get this URL to serve the desired content?

Comment: Thanks for your question.
Very good point. It is another redirection, which works but which is below in the htaccess. It is through the Wordpress

Comment: The WP routing works by checking what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains - and that value does not change, when you do an internal rewrite only. I think instead of handling this via the .htaccess, you should rather use https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule here.

Comment: Many thanks it was the solution!
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add that as an answer to remove this question from the unanswered question queue and to help other readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the documentation here https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

I put it in the function.php of my child theme

```
/* Redirection */ 
  function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^xxxxxxxxxxxxx(.*)','/index.php?p=123&var=$matches[1]','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```